# Notification Of Changed XML Values

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, data-structures, dataset

I guess I'll just flat-out explain my situation. I have a desktop application that reads and writes to an XML file. This same XML file is read and written by an ASP site. Both sides need to be notified when a value changes. This is relatively trivial on the desktop app side as I just re-read the XML and apply the values, however it gets more complicated on the web side.

The website needs to immediately get the updated information from the XML. The problem is I can't figure out a proper way to store these values and in turn handle notification of updated/changed/new/deleted values. Sending the entire XML file is out of the question.

Getting the data to the page isn't the question, I have that all wired up. The question is how should I be storing this data in order to be able to handle incremental updates and also be notified of changed values?

I have an extremely clunky solution and I absolutely hate it. I was hoping someone could maybe point me in the right direction as to what type of container to store this data in; I'm relatively inexperienced in this area of C#/ASP.

Thanks for taking the time to read my novel.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the website getting the update "immediately"? Code would normally only execute there on the next request (whenever that comes). So on every request you *could* (but do not!) just read the latest copy of the file.

In general architecture terms, if you need 2 components / applications co-ordinating like this - a message queue is the natural abstraction. Right now you're treating the XML file like shared memory for doing interprocess communication.

If it's going to remain a kludge like solution - i suggest replacing the XML with a DB table. Easier to poll, co-ordinate and receive updates.

Comment: I completely agree with using a proper DB, but unfortunately I have no control over the desktop application. I'm using the SignalR library (websockets) so I'm able to immediately inform any clients of changes by pushing them out. And as you stated, I'm trying to prevent having to send the entire XML file (which I'm going to use my "kludgy" solution before I ever do that).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kinda found a solution.

I keep a copy of the "current" XML as an XmlSerializer with a proper Type. When I read the new XML, I also read it in as a XmlSerializer but to compare them, I just JSON each and do a standard string compare.

This works for me because my XML structure never changes, just the values inside so I'm able to check to see which "sections" have changed by comparing their serialized JSON.

Kinda weird but it works for me.